# REACTJS - How to have "Good Design" - avoid try to run a child method from parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am beggining with ReactJS and I have a design with 3 layer components.

```js
Dashboard component 
return(<>
   <Button>Refresh All</Button>

   <CustomChart dataChart={name:'test1', type:'pie', apiUrl:'https://abx'}></CustomChart>
   <CustomChart dataChart={name:'test2', type:'line', apiUrl:'https://xyz'}></CustomChart>
   <CustomChart dataChart={name:'test3', type:'bar', apiUrl:'https://tuv'}></CustomChart>
</>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
CustomChart
const loadData = () => {
     //call apiUrl for get data and then set resp to dataChart
}

useEffect(()=>{
   loadData();
},[])

const renderChart = () => {
   switch (chartInfo.type) {
      case 'number':
           return (<NumberChart dataChart={dataChart} />)
      case 'pie':
           return (<PieChart dataChart={dataChart} />)
      case 'line':
            return (<LineChart dataChart={dataChart} />)
            break;
      }
}

return (<div >
  {dataChart && renderChart()}
</div>
)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Detail Chart (PieChartComponent, LineChartComponent,...)
//render chart with data from customChart
```

I know In React it is not a good idea to run a child method and I think I shouldn't call `loadData` function  when I press the refresh button in the parent component.

Can you help me find good design.

Please forgive my english.

Comment: Would you please fix your indentation?

Answer (score 1):

In your `CustomChart` component, you already have most of the code you need,

```js
useEffect(()=>{
   loadData();
}, [])
```

The second argument to `useEffect`, if passed a prop, will only run the effect when that prop changes. [Read more here](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/z1xzaupgpd-run-side-effect-when-a-prop-changes-whooks)

So what needs to happen is, in your Dashboard component you store the state of the last time the button was pressed, `onButtonPress() { this.setState({lastPress: new Date().getTime()})`, and then pass `lastPress` down onto each `CustomChart` as a prop, something like:

```js
<CustomChart 
  updateTime={this.state.lastPress} 
  dataChart={{
    name: 'test1', 
    type:'pie', 
    apiUrl:'https://abx',
  }}
>
</CustomChart>
```

And then update your `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
   loadData();
}, [props.updateTime])
```